How to Convert a Complex Object Consisting of Multiple Configuration Properties with a Custom Spring Converter?
I'm trying to manually convert a set of configuration properties to an object using Spring.
My target class looks like this:
class ComplexConfigurationProperties {
  private final Map<String, ComplexObject> objects;

  public ComplexConfigurationProperties(Map<String, ComplexObject> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
  }
}

And my Converter looks like this:
class CustomConverter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, ComplexObject> {

  @Override
  public ComplexObject convert(Map<String, Object> source) {
    ComplexObject result;
    // do some stuff
    return result;
  }
}

My test for this looks like this:
@Test
void test() {
  DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
  conversionService.addConverter(new CustomConverter());
  ComplexConfigurationProperties props = new Binder(
      Collections.singleton(
          new MapConfigurationPropertySource(
              Map.of(
                  "prefix.objects.a.property1", "property1",
                  "prefix.objects.a.property2", "property2"
              )
          )
      ), null,
      conversionService
  ).bind("prefix", ComplexConfigurationProperties.class).get();

  assertNotNull(props);
}

The binding result is always null and my custom converter is never used. Now my question is: what did I do wrong? Do I need to use a different source type in the converter? Is what I'm trying to do not possible?
I couldn't find anything regarding the conversion of complex types in the documentation.

So, after spending some hours debugging the binder, this approach doesn't seem to work. The binder binds the properties directly to the class that is expected. There seems to be no conversion taking place here.
The only way to affect the binding is by employing a BindingHandler. In its onStart method, you can at least somwhat affect the binding process by replacing the target class (to some extent).
Also, in the onSuccess/onFailure methods, the binding result can be completely replaced.
